# Django | Automatic creation of objects in the model

Tags: python, django, loops

I have two models 'CardsDesk' and 'Card'.

Example:

```
class CardsDesk(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название колоды', blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/',verbose_name='Картинка колоды')


class Card(models.Model):

    CHOICES = [
    ('Мечи', (
            ('Swords_1', 'Туз мечей'),
            ('Swords_2', 'Двойка мечей'),
            ('Swords_3', 'Тройка мечей'),
            ('Swords_4', 'Четверка мечей'),
            ('Swords_5', 'Пятерка мечей'),
            ('Swords_6', 'Шестерка мечей'),
            ('Swords_7', 'Семерка мечей'),
            ('Swords_8', 'Восьмерка мечей'),
            ('Swords_9', 'Девятка мечей'),
            ('Swords_10', 'Десятка мечей'),
            ('Swords_11', 'Паж мечей'),
            ('Swords_12', 'Рыцарь мечей'),
            ('Swords_13', 'Королева мечей'),
            ('Swords_14', 'Король мечей'),
        )
    ),
   ............
```

I need that when I create a Model of type "CardDeck"
Automatically create 78 objects with automatically selected categories.

Any ideas?

I tried the for loop, I tried the def save create(). So far I have absolutely no idea how to implement it.

Edited To make it easier to understand, I use classic cards:

```
CARDS_TYPE = [
    ('Diamonds', 
        ('Diamonds_1', 'Diamonds_1'),
        ('Diamonds_2', 'Diamonds_2'),
    ),
    ('Hearts', 
        ('Hearts_1', 'Hearts_1'),
        ('Hearts_2', 'Hearts_2'),

    ),
    ('Clubs', 
        ('Clubs_1', 'Clubs'),
        ('Clubs_2', 'Clubs'),
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it using [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/).

Assuming the following models in `models.py`:

```py
CARD_TYPE_CHOICES = [
    ('Swords_1', 'Туз мечей'),
    ('Swords_2', 'Двойка мечей'),
    ('Swords_3', 'Тройка мечей'),
    ('Swords_4', 'Четверка мечей'),
    ('Swords_5', 'Пятерка мечей'),
]

class CardDeck(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название колоды', blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/',verbose_name='Картинка колоды')


class Card(models.Model):
    deck = models.ForeignKey(CardDeck, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    card_type = models.CharField(default="Swords_1", choices=CARD_TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=32)
```

Create a file `signals.py` with the following receiver for `post_save` event of the `CardDeck` model:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import CardDeck, Card, CARD_TYPE_CHOICES
 
 
@receiver(post_save, sender=CardDeck)
def create_cards_for_deck(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        cards = (Card(card_type=card_type[0], deck=instance) for card_type in CARD_TYPE_CHOICES)
        Card.objects.bulk_create(cards)
```

Finally, bind the signals to your `apps.py` file like:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig
 
class AppnameConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'appname'
 
    def ready(self):
        import appname.signals
```

Read more about [bulk_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) method.

Comment: My CARD_TYPE_CHOICES has something like this: 

Swords, ('Swords_1', 'Name'), ('Swords_2', 'Name_2')
Woods, ('Woords_1', 'Name'), ('Woods_2', 'Name_2')


I need for each type of Swords, Woods, etc to create cards, each type has 24 cards

In general, the final version should look something like this:

Card_name Swords_1 Card Deck,
Card_Name Swords_2 Card Deck

And so 78 times

Comment: The field choices keyword only accepts a list of tuples of 2 items, hence whatever structure you have of your card types will have to be managed outside the model. I am not able to understand from your comment what you're trying to do, can you maybe create a new question for it if its very different from what was asked here?

Comment: To be simple, I need to create for a new deck automatically cards with suits

Comment: Any ideas for this?